# MODX PdoMenu Вывести ресурс в меню, родитель которого скрыт

Tags: cms, modx

Если родительский ресурс скрыт, то даже, если не скрывать его детей, то они все-равно не отображаются в меню. Как отобразить детей при скрытом родителе?

```
[[pdoMenu? &parents=`0` &level=`3`]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[pdoMenu? &parents=`0,id скрытого родителя` &level=`1`]]
```